# Gnome-Screensaver with Python?

Tags: python, gnome, screensaver

I've created a little screensaver-type program with Python, and I'd like to get it working properly under gnome-screensaver. The documentation is all written for C, and there don't appear to be libraries for Python. Is there any way to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gnome-screensaver doesn't integrate with the screensavers any more than with a small config file that sets the name, some other properties, and a command to execute to start the screensaver. This is documented in the gnome-screensaver FAQ.

The program that gets started needs to get the Window ID from the environment (`XSCREENSAVER_WINDOW`), and start displaying on that window. This is the tricky part, as it's not always obvious how to do that. Most toolkits should have methods to get a handle on an already existing window by giving the ID, so search your GUI-toolkit documentation for something like that.